# Problema com Lista e HashMap

Tags: java, android, hashmap, lista

Tenho uma lista conforme declarado abaixo:

```
List<Map<String, String>> lista = new ArrayList<Map<String, String>>();
```

Map conforme declarado abaixo:

```
Map<String, String> mapa = new HashMap<String, String>();
```

O valores são carregados em um for com resultados de um webservice conforme abaixo:

```
if (propInfo1.getName().toString().equals("competencia")) {
    SoapObject obj2 = (SoapObject) obj1.getProperty(ret1);
    for (int ret2 = 0; ret2 < obj2.getPropertyCount(); ret2++) {
        PropertyInfo propInfo2 = new PropertyInfo();
        obj2.getPropertyInfo(ret2, propInfo2);
        competencia = new Competencia();
        if (propInfo2.getName().toString().equals("codCal")) {
            mapa.put("codcal", obj2.getProperty(ret2).toString());
        }
        if (propInfo2.getName().toString().equals("perRef")) {
            Object objData = (Object) obj2.getProperty(ret2).toString();
            try {
                Date date = DataUtils.stringToDate(objData.toString());
                mapa.put("perref", DataUtils.dataMesAno(date));
            } catch (Exception e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
        if (propInfo2.getName().toString().equals("tipCal")) {
            mapa.put("tipcal", obj2.getProperty(ret2).toString());
        }
    }
    Log.i("Valor do Mapa", mapa.toString());
    lista.add(mapa);
    Log.i("Valor da Lista", lista.toString());
}
```

Porém os valores estão sendo carregados duplicados

```
18704-18704/br.com.fjsa16.holerite I/Valor do Mapa﹕ {tipcal=Cálculo Mensal, perref=Abril / 2015, codcal=405}
18704-18704/br.com.fjsa16.holerite I/Valor da Lista﹕ [{tipcal=Cálculo Mensal, perref=Abril / 2015, codcal=405}]
18704-18704/br.com.fjsa16.holerite I/Valor do Mapa﹕ {tipcal=Cálculo Mensal, perref=Março / 2015, codcal=401}
18704-18704/br.com.fjsa16.holerite I/Valor da Lista﹕ [{tipcal=Cálculo Mensal, perref=Março / 2015, codcal=401}, {tipcal=Cálculo Mensal, perref=Março / 2015, codcal=401}]
```

No logcat o mapa é carregado corretamente mas ao adicionar na lista o mesmo é carregado de forma duplicada, ou seja os valores são os mesmos.

Alguém já se deparou com isso? Podem me ajudar?

Comment: Suspeito que você esteja inializando o objeto mapa em um lugar errado, pode editar tua pergunta e colocar mais código?

Comment: Otávio, era justamente isso... não me atentei! Muito obrigado. Abraço.

Comment: @Otávio podes juntar uma resposta com uma explicação do problema?

Comment: @Sergio na realidade fica complicado pois eu só dei uma sugestão totalmente "no escuro". Golpe de sorte, hehehe.
Acho mais justo o ADP (@FábioAzevedo) colocar uma resposta ele mesmo. :)

Comment: @Fabio Azevedo, poderia colocar a solução, para caso alguém tenha o mesmo problema?

Comment: Pessoal, apenas declarei o HashMap abaixo no if... if (propInfo1.getName().toString().equals("competencia")) {
                        Map<String, String> mapa = new HashMap<String, String>();